Upload a photo returns 'Item type not valid.'
I'm trying to upload a photo using the code below based on ArcGIS Python API:
def handle_attachments_api(
    portal_domain: str,
    portal_username: str,
    portal_password: str,
    data_type: str = None,
    data_url: str = None,
    filename: str = None,
    type_keywords: str = None,
    description: str = None,
    title: str = None,
    url: str = None,
    text: str = None,
    tags: str = None,
    snippet: str = None,
    extent: str = None,
    spatial_reference: str = None,
    access_information: str = None,
    license_info: str = None,
    culture: str = None,
    comments_enabled: bool = True,
    access: str = None,
    overwrite: bool = False,
    data: str = None,
    thumbnail: str = None,
    metadata: str = None,
    owner: str = None,
    folder: str = None,
    item_id: guid = None,
):
gis = GIS(
    url=f"https://{portal_domain}/portal",
    username=portal_username,
    password=portal_password
)

item_properties = {
    "type": data_type,
    "dataUrl": data_url,
    "filename": filename,
    "typeKeywords": type_keywords,
    "description": description,
    "title": title,
    "url": url,
    "text": text,
    "tags": tags,
    "snippet": snippet,
    "extent": extent,
    "spatialReference": spatial_reference,
    "accessInformation": access_information,
    "licenseInfo": license_info,
    "culture": culture,
    "commentsEnabled": comments_enabled,
    "access": access,
    "overwrite": overwrite,
}

gis.content.add(
    item_properties=item_properties,
    data=data,
    thumbnail=thumbnail,
    metadata=metadata,
    owner=owner,
    folder=folder,
    item_id=item_id
)

But I see the error below when I use 'jpg' as item type:
>..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-ps\lib\site->packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py:6837: in add
>    itemid = self._portal.add_item(
>..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-ps\lib\site->packages\arcgis\gis\_impl\_portalpy.py:438: in add_item
>    resp = self.con.post(path, postdata, files)
>..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-ps\lib\site->packages\arcgis\gis\_impl\_con\_connection.py:1524: in post
>    return self._handle_response(
>..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-ps\lib\site->packages\arcgis\gis\_impl\_con\_connection.py:1000: in _handle_response
>    self._handle_json_error(data["error"], errorcode)
>_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
>
>self = <arcgis.gis._impl._con._connection.Connection object at 0x0000026A223A0B20>
>error = {'code': 400, 'details': [], 'message': 'Item type not valid.', 'messageCode': >'CONT_0113'}
>errorcode = 400
>
>    def _handle_json_error(self, error, errorcode):
>        errormessage = error.get("message")
>        # handles case where message exists in the dictionary but is None
>        if errormessage is None:
>            errormessage = "Unknown Error"
>        # _log.error(errormessage)
>        if "details" in error and error["details"] is not None:
>            if isinstance(error["details"], str):
>                errormessage = f"{errormessage} \n {error['details']}"
>                # _log.error(error['details'])
>            else:
>                for errordetail in error["details"]:
>                    if isinstance(errordetail, str):
>                        errormessage = errormessage + "\n" + errordetail
>                        # _log.error(errordetail)
>    
>        errormessage = errormessage + "\n(Error Code: " + str(errorcode) + ")"
>       raise Exception(errormessage)
>E       Exception: Item type not valid.
>E       (Error Code: 400)
>
>..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-ps\lib\site->packages\arcgis\gis\_impl\_con\_connection.py:1023: Exception

Where I can see a list of all allowed items type?

type should be 'Image' (extension should be 'jpg'): https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/items-and-item-types.htm

On your
item_properties = {
    "type": data_type,
    ...
}

change the type to "Image".
